# I am getting a compilation error when I try to deploy my Phoenix Elixir app to Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am very unfamiliar with the deployment process and how to interpret the build log on Heroku. I'm trying to deploy my Phoenix Elixir app and have gone through the process as outlined on https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/heroku.html. However, I am get the following error in my build logs:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-1062-aws
   npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_cb2fdf13a1883f06eae3f7c5297f7b64/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_cb2fdf13a1883f06eae3f7c5297f7b64/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "run" "deploy"
   npm ERR! node v6.9.2
   npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! @ deploy: `webpack --mode production`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! Failed at the @ deploy script 'webpack --mode production'.
   npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
   npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
   npm ERR!     webpack --mode production
   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
   npm ERR!     npm bugs
   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
   npm ERR!     npm owner ls
   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
   npm ERR!     /tmp/build_cb2fdf13a1883f06eae3f7c5297f7b64/assets/npm-debug.log
```

I've updated to the latest version of node.js and npm as the logs suggested.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't with the version of node that you have locally. If you look at the logs it shows that *heroku* is trying to use node v6.9.2. That is a really old version of node that won't work. You need to use heroku-buildpack-phoenix-static so that you can define the node version the heroku is trying to use. Add the buildpack with the cli:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/gjaldon/heroku-buildpack-phoenix-static.git
```

Then create a file phoenix_static_buildpack.config in your project root directory. In that file define the version of node to use:

```
node_version=12.18.1
```

This will tell heroku to use that version of node. After that try to redeploy and the issue should be resolved.

If you have more issues then check out the phoenix docs on deploying to heroku. It has a lot of useful information:
https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/heroku.html

Comment: Thanks, I was running into the same issue and this fixed it